# AWS Cognito JWT authentication works with the ID Token, but not the Access Token? Returns 401

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, jwt, amazon-cognito

I've followed this tutorial to a tee:
http://snevsky.com/blog/dotnet-core-authentication-aws-cognito

```
response.AuthenticationResult
```

The AuthenticationResult object allows me to fetch the signed in user's access token, id token & refresh token.

The only problem is, that I can only actually authenticate and access my API endpoint with an [Authorize] attribute, by using

```
Authorization Bearer [ID Token]
```

When in reality, I should be using the Access Token. When switching out the ID Token in the header of my requests to the Access Token, I always get a 401 back.

I have also tried removing "Bearer" to no avail.

Has anyone ever come across this before? I'm baffled and it almost suggests to me that AWS Cognito, is not functioning correctly out of the box?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Cognito uses id token to connect to STS and retrieve credentials. So it is the "correct" behavior according to their own [conference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZqG7HjT2AQ&feature=youtu.be&t=9m50s)

Answer (score 0):

You can access with id and access token.

Read this article: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html

> The identity token is used to authorize API calls based on identity claims of the signed-in user. The access token is used to authorize API calls based on the custom scopes of specified access-protected resources.

However, it is complicated to have 2 tokens, as you would have to use the id_token to access and the access_token to perform actions related to the user (such as change_password).

To use only the access_token you need to define the custom scope in the authorization statement of your lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

If you set 'ValidateAudience' to FALSE in JwtBearerOptions -> TokenValidationParameters, it should work. The default is true.